# When using inset, rest of the face becomes angled

Tags: mesh

I am trying to create 3 squares on a face; so I use the inset tool. But then the rest of the face becomes angeled so I cant inset it. I feel like there is an easier way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Add 2 vertical loop cuts and inset the resulting 3 faces the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Before insetting the middle face, try adding loopcuts along the width of your object. Hit ctrl+R, run your mouse wheel once or hit 2 on the number row, left-click to add and finally right-click to cancel the consecutive slide operation. Now that you have three faces instead of one, you can select all of them and do the inset. Remember to toggle "individual" by hitting I while doing the inset.